# IOS share extension show alert if user is not logged in?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8-share-extension

I had added share extension to upload file.

But i want to stop open share extension when user is not logged in application and show alert similar like Messenger application from facebook.

[Facebook messenger app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNwCu.jpg)

How can i do this
**Note : I know how to do check is User logged in or not using app groups. But I want to check before open the share extension and show alert. in my case its first open the share extension and then i am showing alert. I want to check before open the share extension**

Answer (score 2):

Rather than directly open your custom view for share extension you could use alert first to check if user logged in or not, then if user has logged in, you can proceed to present your custom view with animation.

you can do this by adding below method on `ShareViewController: SLComposeServiceViewController`.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    // check if user logged in or not here and if not below code will be executed.
    self.loginAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "Please launch application from the home screen before continuing.", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
    let onOk = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .destructive) { alert in
        self.extensionContext?.cancelRequest(withError: NSError(domain: "loging", code: 0, userInfo: nil))
    }
    loginAlertController!.addAction(onOk)
    present(loginAlertController!, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Though I use this, the default UI is still showing up in the background.

Comment: Default UI will be definitely in background, To prevent that, make another empty SLComposeServiceViewController and do this login check there. After that if user is logged in - you can redirect to your UI.

Comment: What do you mean by "Make another  EMPTY SLComposeServiceViewController". The above code is that empty SLComposeServiceViewController which takes the user to an AlertView Controller.

Comment: Is this allowed by Apple?

Answer (score 1):

You should make use of **App groups** to communicate between the main app and extension app.***(Sharing Data: NSUserDefaults and App Groups
)***

You can add data in main app like this :-

```
let mySharedDefaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.yourValue")
     mySharedDefaults?.set(false, forKey: "isLoggedIn")
```

Then you can get data like this in your extension

```
   let mySharedDefaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.yourValue")
         if let isLoggedIn = mySharedDefaults?.value(forKey: "isLoggedIn") as? Bool {
            if !isLoggedIn {
                     showAlert()
           }
}
```

[Refer this](http://blog.intrepid.io/ios-app-extensions) for implementing app groups

Comment: I know how to do check is User logged in or not. But I want to check before open the share extension and show alert

Comment: Your application's module must load at least onto memory for getting data about user login status. So before opening share extension, you can't get your application data related to user login status.

Comment: @SharadPaghadal have you seend screenshot i had added in question. How they do it..

Comment: i'm posting an answer

Comment: @SShah Setting the background to clear color and showing the alert would resolve the issue.(WORK AROUND).

Comment: From Apple's documentation…  `synchronize()` _"… this method is unnecessary and shouldn't be used."_ https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults/1414005-synchronize

Comment: @AshleyMills Thanks .I have made the change.